# Deferreds on jQuery.each result

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm learing deferreds, and can not work out how/why this works:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        1</div>
    <div>
        2</div>
    <div>
        3</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("div").each(function (i) {
            $(this).delay(1000 * i).fadeOut();
        }).promise().done(function () { console.log("it's done"); });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In prarticular: **why can I call promise after each? Why it's technically possible?** I've console.logged:

```
console.log($("div").each(function (i) {}));
```

and I do see **promise** method in prototype. But, my each function do not return any values, there's simply a :

```
$(this).delay(1000 * i).fadeOut();
```

**So how promise is connected to animation result? (basically each iteration's result)**

**EDIT 1: Just to make it clear, perhaps I should have written my question like this:**

How it's done that **done** method is called after all animations are finished == how promise is interconnected to animation that is executed inside the each callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the `promise()` method *inside* the block? At the moment you're only executing it after all the iteration has finished.

```
$("div").each(function (i) {
   $(this).delay(1000 * i).fadeOut().promise().done(function () { console.log("This individual animation is done."); });
}).promise().done(function () { console.log("Everything is done."); });
```

---

Your selector `div` actually refers to quite a few elements on your page. As it iterates through them all, it executes a specific action to this element.

What you're then doing is asking jQuery to execute another action when all previous actions tied to those elements have finished. According to their documentation, it returns an object:

> when all actions of a certain type bound to the collection, queued or
>   not, have finished.

So, after **every** `fadeOut()` has executed in the collection, the `console.log()` is activated.

Comment: Well, this is what I'm testing - execute it after all iterations has finished. And I'm curious how it works :) I saw it in one tutorial, and it gave me food for thought

Comment: So does my answer provide what you need?

Comment: Nope. I'm curious how it's done that done methods is called after all animations are finished == how promise is interconnected to animation result.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you're interested or would like to know about anything specific, mention it so I can help :)

Comment: How does promise() call on each() result knows, that function executed for each element has started a queued action? I think this is the essence of my question :)

Comment: The method returns a dynamically generated object that, according to jQuery documentation, "is resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have ended." Each member of your loop is a member of the collection because they have the same selector. The jQuery framework then tracks each event/function executed on each element internally, and generates a promise object when each member has finished. In terms of the internal/core JavaScript which makes jQuery work, I have no idea.

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen `each` being used with promises, but only animation

```js
$('div') 
.animate({opacity: 0}, 1500) // animate all divs at once
.promise()
.done(function(){ 
   console.log('all done');
});
```

this will animate all divs at once, then execute the callback when all divs finished animating.
the problem with animate inside a looping is that it can't be coordinated and you won't be able to control when they all finished if you don't use promises. If you really want to use `each`, you'd have to make an array of `promises`, then use `then`

```js
 var promises = [];
 $('div').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    promises.push($this.fadeOut('slow').promise());
 });

 $.when.apply($, promises).then(function(){
   console.log('all done');
 });
```

This isn't the same as doing `$('div').fadeOut('slow', function(){ alert('done'); });` because the callback will happen for EACH element animated, while the promises deal like it was a "task" with many subtasks

http://jsfiddle.net/LbHrQ/3/

The best use of promises is when you want to synchronize some asynchronous operations by nature, like animations, ajax, things that use timeouts (in this case, you need to `resolve()` your Deferred manually)